# Washing before prayer (specifically Shema

Tags: tefilla, shema, netilat-yadayim-washing

I know the morning requires 3 times, but during other times of the day, is it required to wash 3 times before prayer (mainly wondering about the Shema), or is only 1 time ok?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35272/washing-before-davening-1-or-3-times

Comment: I'm pretty sure when it comes to washing before davening (not after waking up) that the main thing is cleanliness. So yes I think 1 time is ok as long as it cleans your hands.